# xcode 5 scrollview doesnt allow me to go all the way down with out it "bouncing"

Tags: ios

Is there a way to have each label equal distances apart depending on how many lines are displaying per table cell.  I can see all the data if I use both hands to tug the info up the screen but that isnt user friendly.

Comment: Have you looked at using a `UICollectionView`? This might fill the space better than a `UITableView` which I'm assuming you're using.

Comment: no I havent looked at collectionview, does it need to be embedded and should I drag all my info into one or will it not go that easily?

Comment: Google 'UICollectionView'. There are tutorials everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have `UILabel`s in `UITableViewCells`? You may need to adjust the height of the cells via `UITableViewDelegate`'s `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` message. In there, you probably want to calculate your height using `boundingRectForSize:options:attributes:context:` from `NSString` (iOS 7 and later). Make sure the `numberOfLines` property in your `UILabel` is 0 to adjust for the expanding height, and set the appropriate constraints.

Comment: the labels are in the detailview controller and description 12 line paragraphs, these are the onew that arent equally dispersed and easy to scroll.

Comment: @Krista: Please update your question with more concise language of your problem, what you're trying to do, and the steps you've taken to try to solve it. I'm having a difficult time understanding what you're asking and what you have already done.

Comment: I have a tableview that leads to a detail view controller.  In the detail there are 4 paragraphs separated by a line.  I cant get the constraints to work out where now matter how much content the paragraph has I would like to be able to scroll all the way to the bottom. I saw something about "neighbor" constraints on stackoverflow but cant seem to find it again.

Comment: @Krista are all paragraphs in the same `UILabel`, and that `UILabel` in a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: each paragraph is its own UILabel and those 4 labels are in one UIScrollview so that it can all be read in one long form.

Comment: @Krista then you don't have your `contentOffset` set large enough for all the objects in your `UIScrollView`. You need the contentOffset to be at least as tall as the bottom of the last `UILabel`.